# Should I pass an argument before a period or between parenthesis?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why are arguments in Python methods and/or functions sometimes passed before a period and other times they are inside parentheses? For example,  `argument.function()` or `function(argument)`.

Is there some rule about when or why it should be called a certain way? I find it difficult to remember which way it is supposed to be for certain functions.

Comment: Dot notation is used for modules, methods, and attributes. Have you used classes at all?

Comment: `argument.function()` -- umm, where did you see this as a convention? It is usually `classInstance.method()` or `module.function()`. Arguments still come between parentheses.

Comment: I'm assuming you're referencing cases such as `"-".join(my_list)`, right?

Comment: Real examples would be useful.

Comment: What you're describing as `argument.function()` is really `instance.method()`. It doesn't work for arbitrary functions' first arguments; it **only** works for the instance position in methods. As such, you should use it when you're invoking a method _and at no other time_.

Comment: @guy, yes. Stuff like that.

Comment: Ah! Thanks, @Firelord. So the difference is between methods and functions. I thought they were synonymous.

Comment: Thanks, @Charles Duffy. I'll have to research those terms (like 'instance') in Python.

Answer (score 3):

What you're describing are **functions** and **methods**. A **method** is somewhat similar to a **function**, except it is associated with objects/classes (you can find more information within [this Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#instance-objects)).

For example, a **function** you call often in Python is `print()`. `print()` is a standard function and is not associated with any object. You may call this function at any time you wish because of this.

A **method** is called first by binding to a specific object, using dot notation. A common method you may call when working with, say, string objects, might be `lower()` which makes a string lowercase. To call this, you would write `text.lower()` where `text` is a variable containing some string.

You can not call `lower()` by itself, nor can you write `lower(text)`, as the method must be bound to the object that it is operating on. Here is some example code:

```py
text = 'Hello, here is some text that contains Mixed Case letters.'
new_text = text.lower()
print(new_text)  # new_text now contains text but in all lowercase
print(text)  # text remains unmodified
```

As for why it's like this, that is largely due Python's design using Object-Oriented Programming (OOP) principles. To help remember, you do need to spend time using the code and reading the documentation. A good question to ask yourself when coding is, "Is this function associated with an object?"